# WordPress rewrite rule is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site, and I have to redirect the user to `wp-login.php` when he types `login2` in the URL. I need this without using `.htaccess`

I tried the following code, but its not working

```
function my_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'login2', 'wp-login.php', 'top' );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init' , 'my_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: I tried this example:

[planetozh.com/blog/2011/01/pretty-login-url-a-simple-rewrite-api-plugin-example/](http://planetozh.com/blog/2011/01/pretty-login-url-a-simple-rewrite-api-plugin-example/)

But it's not working for me.

Comment: Please add some details, such as what you're trying to do and how, exactly, this program is not working. In its current state this question is not answerable.

Comment: The regex passed to the add_rewrite_rule function is incorrect. The answer from @johnnyd23 below has correct regex you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your regex to the following. I've tested and it works, however the flush_rewrite_rules will not work as you have it - shouldn't be called on init hook. Easiest way is to go to permalink settings and re-save in order to flush.

```
function my_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^login2$', 'wp-login.php', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'my_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

**More on Regex**

^ marks the beginning of a string
$ marks the end of a string

Your regex would have actually worked fine without these characters but it would have also matched anything containing that string, such as /login23 or /alogin2. This is simply better practice.

Comment: "Easiest way is to go to permalink settings and re-save in order to flush." this saved me, thanks

Comment: How about elaborating on what the special characters in the regex does? I'm fairly certain elaborating on the use of `^` and `$` in this context would be a massive benefit for anyone who's not already familiar with regex (such as the people who will find the question in future).

Answer (score 1):

1. It is specifically stated on the [Codex page for `flush_rewrite_rules`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) that flushing on `init` is a bad practice. If you're using a plugin flush on enable/disable.
2. Since you're not using .htaccess you can make the flush *soft* by specifying the first parameter as `false`.
3. For rewrites to work you'll need to configure your webserver. This can vary depending on which one you use. Since you can't use htaccess I'll take a while guess you're using nginx, in which case you need to look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx). If you are running Apache there is no way to make rewrites work without htaccess / rewrite rules in your VHost config. You can however use this [half-baked workaround](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite)

Comment: I refered http://planetozh.com/blog/2011/01/pretty-login-url-a-simple-rewrite-api-plugin-example/ and in this example, it says we can do this with out .htacces file